# How to stack a widget below a TextField and make it grows to the bottom as more content loaded?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make this kind of input field.

[image: widget to be achieved]

I found a `flutter_chip_input` package in pubdev that already serve this functionality but it was kinda buggy. I have no time to wait for the next update of the plugin so I decided to move on and build it my self.

In web app, I can easily achieve this design using relative-absolute property in css and some javascript.

Yes, I already tried using Stack widget, but the problem is the `Container` (a wrapper of the white list in the bottom of the input field) won't stick to the bottom.

Whenever more content is loaded, the height grows to the top instead of going to the bottom, causing the input field to be hidden below the container.

I only need to know about how to make the list stick to the bottom of the input field and make the height grows to the bottom. I'll take care the rest of it.

Any clue? Please have a look at my current script:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        decoration: widget.decoration,
        onChanged: (String query) {
          print(query);
        },
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: -30,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Text('asdasdasd'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, I see you are a man of culture as well.

Comment: Yee.. culture goes brrrr..

Comment: Have a mal account? Mine's the same as my stack username

Comment: It's Furukawaaaa ... Just created it today tho. Haha.. now tell me how to use it xD

Comment: Search for the anime u watched and add it under the five tags that r given. U can update the number of episodes  watched, when u watched and how u rate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OverlayEntry` to make it float and `CompositeTransformTarget` and `CompositeTransformFollower` combined with `LayerLink` so the list will stick to the bottom of input.

You can read this article for example implementation

[Flutter: Using Overlay to display floating widgets](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9)

Comment: Cool... This is exactly what I wanted. Now I only need to think how to place the chip and control the cursor on an inserted chip event. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Ryoko hello, did you ever manage to finish this implementation? With a way to control the cursor as well? Would you mind sharing the code? I m trying to achieve something similiar! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `searchDelegate` widget if you're okay with it occupying the full screen. It's quite simple to use.

Docs here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html

EDIT: My bad, it is not necessary to use it in the appBar. Call

`showSearch(context: context, delegate: SearchDel());` from anywhere. It takes up the full screen tho.

If not, I'll have to add the code for the widget. Thought of some ways to make it.

Comment: It will be used everywhere in non-app bar widget, sir.

Comment: Yep yep yep, sorry. But is full screen is fine tho?

Comment: hmm.. i don't think the user gonna love the UX if I go that way, but i think it gonna work.

Comment: Coz searchDelegate really has a lot of options. It's only downside is the full screen. Let me know if it isn't fine I'll try making a widget

Answer (score 0):

How About This? without Stack juga bisa kok

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: 200,
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (String query) {
            print(query);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 100,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Text('asdasdasd'),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Text('asdasdasd'),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Text('asdasdasd'),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: it won't float above the other widget.